# Navigated automatically to wrong page after clicking in a button

Tags: ionic2

I am newbie in ionic2, I have made a list of events with sliding Edit and Delete buttons. I have wanted to view the event details page by tapping on the row and it works fine. But if I tap on the edit button, the edit page appears and immediately replaced by event detail page. My code is following:

```
 <ion-list>   
<ion-item-sliding  *ngFor="let event of eventList" (click)='goToEventDetail(event.id)'>
  <ion-item><p><strong>{{event?.eventName}}</strong><p>
  <p>Place: <strong>{{event?.place}}</strong></p>
  <p>Date: <strong >{{event?.date}}</strong></p>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item-options>
  <button ion-button color="primary" (click)="goToEditEventDetail(event.id)"><ion-icon name='clipboard'></ion-icon> Edit</button>
  <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="removeEvent(event.id)"><ion-icon name='trash'></ion-icon> Delete</button>
</ion-item-options>
</ion-item-sliding >
```

I have tried by removing "(click)='goToEventDetail(event.id)" event from "ion-item-sliding", in that case I have got expected result. My finding is, after clicking to edit button it fires "goToEditEventDetail" event and after that it also fires "goToEventDetail". I need to stop firing the second event, is there any solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post your ts code so that we can check whats wrong with your goToEditEventDetail() function

Comment: Found the solution, just shifted "(click)='goToEventDetail(event.id)" from      "<ion-item-sliding>" to "<ion-item>" :)